# Is a PLC program capacity interchangeable

Tags: memory, plc, interchange

Lets say my process currently uses a PLC with 100K steps and the memory capacity of 160K words DM: 32K words EM: 32K words× 4 banks (OMRON CJ2H-CPU65). I have a spare PLC that is rated at 150K steps and the memory capacity of 352K words DM: 32K words EM: 32K words × 10 banks (OMRON CJ2H-CPU66).

If I needed to replace the OMRON CJ2H-CPU65 with the OMRON CJ2H-CPU66, could this be achieved quickly? I am not very familiar with PLC programming and I am afraid the memory addressing is different for each PLC. Basically, can the PLC program be loaded from a CJ2H-CPU65 to a CJ2H-CPU66 without modification?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to replace a CJ2H-CPU65 with the larger CJ2H-CPU66 and everything should work fine (assuming that all other configuration remains the same).

The same is not necessarily true going the other way, even if the program itself fits in the available memory, since there can be (and are, in the case of CPU66->CPU65) available addressable user memory banks in the EM (Extended Memory) area which are not available in the smaller unit.